# Stacking game around 1993-1996

Tags: identify-this-game

I remember playing a game when I was younger you had 4 plastic pegs and 9 blocks. only 3 blocks could fit onto a peg at a time. The blocks had different colours and numbers. You pulled a card out of a pile and had to arrange the blocks into the same order as was on the card. You could only move a 1 block 1 peg forward or back at a time. You could play by yourself or against another player.